# How to display actions for a local notification when it arrives on the lock screen in the notification center

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

My app sends local notifications. When they come in the active state of the device, then with a swipe down I can access the notification actions.

[image]

But when the notification arrives on the locked screen, there is no access to actions.

[image]

And if I click on the notification, then only "open app" is available to me.

[image]

How can I be able to use these buttons by clicking on a notification in the notification center

It's my code:

```
class Notifications: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    
    func requestAuthorization() {
        notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            
            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
    }
    
    func getNotificationSettings() {
        notificationCenter.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        }
    }

    func scheduleAlarm(date: Date, repeats: Bool) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        let userAction = "Alarm"
        
        content.title = "Будильник"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "alarm.mp3"))
        content.categoryIdentifier = userAction
        
        let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: repeats)
        
        let identifier = "Alarm"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                            content: content,
                                            trigger: trigger)
        
        notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "Snooze", title: "Отложить на 5 мин", options: [])
        let stopAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "Stop", title: "Отключить", options: [.destructive])
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(
            identifier: userAction,
            actions: [snoozeAction, stopAction],
            intentIdentifiers: [],
            options: [])
        
        notificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([category])
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

            completionHandler([.banner, .sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
            print("Dismiss Action")
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
            print("default")
        case "Snooze":
            scheduleAlarm(date: StorageManager.shared.getDatesForDatePickers().wakeUpDate + TimeInterval(60), repeats: false)
        default:
            break
        }

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes there is an access to notifications on lock screen when you make long press on notification (not the swipe down)

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same issue now, did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can achieve this on tap action
Here controller that have start button to fire notification after 5 sec.
When long press on it there is two snooze after 5 sec or comment show as a title of notification in next 5 sec.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    //MARK: Properties and outlets
    let time:TimeInterval = 10.0
    let snooze:TimeInterval = 5.0
    var isGrantedAccess = false
    @IBOutlet weak var commentsLabel: UILabel!
    //MARK: - Functions
    
    
    func setCategories(){
//        Add actions
        let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "snooze", title: "Snooze 5 Sec", options: [])
         let commentAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "comment", title: "Add Comment", options: [], textInputButtonTitle: "Add", textInputPlaceholder: "Add Comment Here")
//        Add actions to category
        let alarmCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "alarm.category",actions: [snoozeAction,commentAction],intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
//        ADd category to notification
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([alarmCategory])
    }
    
    func addNotification(content:UNNotificationContent,trigger:UNNotificationTrigger?, indentifier:String){
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: indentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {
            (errorObject) in
            if let error = errorObject{
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription) in notification \(indentifier)")
            }
        })
    }
    
    //MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isGrantedAccess{
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Alarm"
            content.subtitle = "First Alarm"
            content.body = "First Alarm"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
            content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm.category"
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: time, repeats: false)
            addNotification(content: content, trigger: trigger , indentifier: "Alarm")
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: [.alert,.sound,.badge],
            completionHandler: { (granted,error) in
                self.isGrantedAccess = granted
                if granted{
                    self.setCategories()
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification Access", message: "In order to use this application, turn on notification permissions.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(alertAction)
                    self.present(alert , animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
        })
    }
    
    // MARK: - Delegates
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let identifier = response.actionIdentifier
        let request = response.notification.request
//        handle tap of snooze
        if identifier == "snooze"{
            let newContent = request.content.mutableCopy() as! UNMutableNotificationContent
            newContent.body = "Snooze 5 Seconds"
            newContent.subtitle = "Snooze 5 Seconds"
            let newTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: snooze, repeats: false)
            addNotification(content: newContent, trigger: newTrigger, indentifier: request.identifier)
            
        }
        
//        handle tap of comment
        if identifier == "comment"{
            let textResponse = response as! UNTextInputNotificationResponse
            commentsLabel.text = textResponse.userText
            let newContent = request.content.mutableCopy() as! UNMutableNotificationContent
            newContent.body = textResponse.userText
            addNotification(content: newContent, trigger: request.trigger, indentifier: request.identifier)
        }
        
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```